# Django manytomany filter with contains

Tags: django

I have `groups` in my app which can have multiple `employees`  and multiple `modules`

```
class GroupModels(models.Model):

    model_choices = (('Product', 'Product'), ('Kit', 'Kit'), ('Vendor', 'Vendor'), ('Warehouse', 'Warehouse'))

    model = models.CharField(max_length=500, choices=model_choices)


class Group(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0)
    modules = models.ManyToManyField(GroupModels)
    employees = models.ManyToManyField(Employee)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now while creating permissions for a particular module e.g. `Product`,  I want to check if the user i.e. `employee` in any of the groups have this module. How do I do that ?

I created two groups with the user, one contains the product and other doesn't and use this :

```
     abc = Group.objects.filter(employees__pk=request.user.pk, modules__model='Product').exists()
        print('abc', abc)
        return abc
```

Is this the right way to do this?

Comment: I'm not very sure what your syntax mean (it's indented like a function but no function is declared, but for the query, I would have tried this: `Group.objects.filter(employees=request.user, modules.model='Product').exists()` (you do not need to look for pk for the first part, for the second, `modules` field is a `GroupModel` so it has the `model` attribute)

Comment: modules.model='Product' is not permitted and would cause a SyntaxError. The proper way to query related fields is concat field name of the relationship attribute with the property separated by double underscore. What he did with "modules__model" is actually correct. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships